# How to convert this Oracle statement to T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql

How do I convert the below code to T-SQL ?

```
to_number(to_char(add_months(trunc(SYSDATE),4),'mm'))
```

Comment: This is pretty bad even in Oracle. If you only need the month anyway, why do you need to truncate` SYSDATE` first? You don't. And the `TO_NUMBER` applied to `TO_CHAR` is pretty bad too. In Oracle it should be `extract(month from add_months(sysdate, 4))`. Which would make it that much easier - apparently - to write the T-SQL equivalent.  And... why the `plsql` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
month(dateadd(MONTH, 4, getdate()))
```

Test it with `SELECT month(dateadd(MONTH, 4, getdate()))` and you will have as a result the number of the month (now plus 4)